# How to test if `@Transactional` annotation works as expected

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I do have a case where the `@Transactional` annotation was used on a method with `package-private` scope. It turned out that the transaction does not work in this method.

Is there a way to write a RED test to prove this? How can we test if a transaction was opened for a method, or if a rollback was made when an exception occurred. I thought about an INT test, but not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: The only way I am aware this can be done is to not use the annotation and rather use the Transaction Manager to retrieve a existing/create a new transaction (the problem with the private function not having a transaction would not have been a problem either)

Comment: That would be too time consuming (both in terms of implementing, and in terms of running the tests). You need just one test to check that @Transactional works in general, and for the rest I'd look into static code analysis. Also, on your Repository level put `@Transactional` with propagation=MANDATORY. So that your code fails if your services forgot to start a tx.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev the Repository annotation won't actually fail if it's in a subfunction of a bean aswell tho...
It's also not really sensical as atomicity isn't defined by repositories and using a repository without transactions should be fine (in most cases): https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-transaction-best-practices/

Comment: @EatonEmmerich, I'm not sure you understood me correctly. You don't put `propagation=MANDATORY` to start a tx. You put it to detect if the method was invoked outside of a tx. And no - Repository should not be invoked outside of a tx as this would lead to the autocommit.

Comment: That's my point though, sometimes autocommit is the required behaviour. and a annotation on a repo prevents that, normally a repository has more than one usecase

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom implementation of `TransactionInterceptor` intercepting all invocations of `@Transactional`-annotated methods and incrementing invocation count:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  public static class MyTransactionInterceptor extends TransactionInterceptor {
    //implement counter with e.g. LongAdder
  }
    
  @Bean
  public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource) {
    TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new MyTransactionInterceptor();
    interceptor.setTransactionAttributeSource(transactionAttributeSource);
    return interceptor;
  }  
}
```

As soon as your method is package-private it's available from the test class residing in the same package under `/test` directory. In other words if your code looks like

```java
package com.my.app;

@Service
public class SomeService {

  @Transactional
  void foo() {
   //...
  }
}
```

and the path to this class is `/project-root/src/main/java/com/my/app/SomeService.java`
you create a test class located in `/project-root/src/test/java/com/my/app/SomeServiceTest.java`
(here we assume that you use standard Maven-based project structure):

```java
package com.my.app;

@SpringBootTest
class SomeServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  private SomeService service;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Test
  void foo() {
    //make sure there's no ongoing transaction  
    assertFalse(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    long beforeCount = countTransactions();
    service.foo(); //no compilation error as we are in the same package
    long afterCount = countTransactions();
    //this is going to fail as afterCount is the same as beforeCount
    assertEquals(afterCount, beforeCount + 1);
  }

  private long countTransactions() {
    return context.getBean(MyTransactionInterceptor.class).getTransactionCount();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the transaction interceptor would do the trick nicely!

Comment: This will work for transaction annotations that have the default propagation strategy - to be fair, the OP didn't specify a propagation strategy to test for. I think that apart from the `REQUIRED` propagation, none of the other strategies will be handled with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You need an integration tests for this feature because you want to check how your implementation integrates with Spring's transaction management. So you'll need a Spring application context for the test, with your Spring components needed for this feature - you probably will try to reuse as much as possible your production app context (maybe changing the persistence configuration to use an in memory db). You should replace one or more of your components with a mock that would throw an exception that would trigger the transaction rollback - you can set this as a primary autowiring candidate for your test or use some other way to set this object so it's used by the code you're testing.
Then write tests to check all is working in normal conditions and also in case of rollbacks. Probably there are multiple rollback scenarios you'll test having multiple places where exceptions can occur and also maybe special behavior for some of those exceptions.

An additional step would be to include in your CI/CD pipeline tools that automatically analyze code for common problems. I know Sonar detects this particular problem and many others.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a specific test, just read the doc:

> When you use transactional proxies with Spring’s standard configuration, you should apply the @Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private, or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings. If you need to annotate non-public methods, consider the tip in the following paragraph for class-based proxies or consider using AspectJ compile-time or load-time weaving (described later).

See the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for more details

Comment: @akuma8 isn't wrong. You generally don't want or need to test library code, just your own code. So you may want to test how your code *uses* `@Transactional`, but not specifically the annotation behavior itself.

Comment: @Jorn that would be atleast one more piece of information that wasn't given: "verify that class/method annotations include the 'Transaction' annotation"

Comment: also i think you misrepresent the complexity of this topic as a whole:
https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth